# Not able to send kafka message when MessageHistory is enabled with Spring Boot 2

Tags: spring-integration, spring-kafka

I am upgrading one of our services from spring boot 1.5 to 2, and now I am seeing an exception related to kafka producer related to writing messageHistory to the header. Here is the exception recevied:

```
org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Incorrect type specified for header 'history'. Expected [class org.springframework.integration.history.MessageHistory] but actual type is [class org.springframework.kafka.support.DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper$NonTrustedHeaderType].
```

By digging into the code, it looks like the exception was thrown in `DefaultKafkaHeaderrMapper` when converting the `MessageHistory` header https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/14157742d7fa51ce8a22dfbdccc2e3c5b43c1c6f/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/support/DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper.java#L253-L275  so anyone can help me understand:

1. is `MessageHistory` supposed to be written to the message before
   sending out?
2. if the answer to 1) is yes, what's the right way to make `MessageHistory` to the trusted packages?
3. if 1) is no, what might have been done incorrectly to prevent the history to be written to the header?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can add that `org.springframework.integration.history` package to white list to restore previous behavior though: `DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper.addTrustedPackages()`:

```
/**
 * Add packages to the trusted packages list (default {@code java.util, java.lang}) used
 * when constructing objects from JSON.
 * If any of the supplied packages is {@code "*"}, all packages are trusted.
 * If a class for a non-trusted package is encountered, the header is returned to the
 * application with value of type {@link NonTrustedHeaderType}.
 * @param packagesToTrust the packages to trust.
 */
public void addTrustedPackages(String... packagesToTrust) {
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#headers

Or you can exclude such a header from mapping altogether.

Another way to add a custom serializer to store that `MessageHistory` as a `List`.